# All shortest paths code: PropertyValue error $Failed (Edited to narrow and with added code example that does run fine on a different graph)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am working on the following code (to generate all shortest paths in a graph)

It executes fine until the last two lines.

PropertyValue[{g, t}, "ShortestPaths"] gives $Failed

Is there an issue with the use of PropertyValue in this context?

The code below sets up a graph, then runs code to determine all shortest paths from the source s.

The functions discoverFun and rediscoverFun are taken from Mathematica documentation (BreadthFirstScan and its applications on shortest paths). These functions are used to generate *all* shortest paths.

PropertyValue (at end of code) returns $Failed. Is there an issue with the use of PropertyValue?

The graph produced is the following:

[image]

The output of BreadthFirstScan is the following:

[image]

However, after this point, PropertyValue[{g, t}, "ShortestPaths"] gives $Failed.

Following the code, an example of an alternative graph example is given on which the code does execute fine.

```
BlingA[tree_, tPosition_] := ReplacePart[tree, tPosition -> aLpha];

BlingB[tree_, tPosition_] := 
Module[{time, updatedTree}, updatedTree = BlingA[tree, tPosition];
time = 333;
{tree, time, updatedTree}];

TestPositions[sourceTree_, targetTree_] := 
Complement[Position[sourceTree, bEta], Position[targetTree, bEta]];

AllupdatedTrees[sourceTree_, targetTree_] := 
Fold[BlingA[#1, #2] &, sourceTree, #] & /@ 
Subsets[TestPositions[sourceTree, targetTree]];

FanOutBlingBs[sourceTree_, targetTree_] := 
BlingA[sourceTree, #] & /@ TestPositions[sourceTree, targetTree];

FanOutBlingBsTimes[sourceTree_, targetTree_] := 
BlingB[sourceTree, #] & /@ TestPositions[sourceTree, targetTree];

ResultGraph[sourceTree_, targetTree_] := Module[{edges},
edges = 
Flatten[FanOutBlingBsTimes[#, targetTree] & /@ 
  AllupdatedTrees[sourceTree, targetTree], 1];
Graph[(#[[1]] -> #[[3]]) & /@ edges, 
EdgeWeight -> (#[[2]] & /@ edges), EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[10, Background -> White], 
VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[10, Background -> White]]
];



s =  bEta[bEta[bEta[1, 2 ], 3 ], 4];
t = aLpha[aLpha[aLpha[1 , 2], 3], 4]; 


g = ResultGraph[s, t]

PropertyValue[{g, s}, "ShortestPaths"] = {{s}}; 
PropertyValue[{g, s}, "Distance"] = 0;

discoverFun[u_, v_, d_] := 
If[u != v, 
PropertyValue[{g, u}, "ShortestPaths"] = 
Table[Append[p, u], {p, PropertyValue[{g, v}, "ShortestPaths"]}]; 
PropertyValue[{g, u}, "Distance"] = d]

rediscoverFun[u_, v_] := 
If[PropertyValue[{g, u}, "Distance"] == 
PropertyValue[{g, v}, "Distance"] + 1, 
PropertyValue[{g, u}, "ShortestPaths"] = 
Join[PropertyValue[{g, u}, "ShortestPaths"], 
Table[Append[p, u], {p, PropertyValue[{g, v}, "ShortestPaths"]}]]]

BreadthFirstScan[g, s, {"DiscoverVertex" -> discoverFun, 
"VisitedVertex" -> rediscoverFun, 
"UnvisitedVertex" -> rediscoverFun}]


PropertyValue[{g, t}, "ShortestPaths"]

Table[HighlightGraph[g, p], {p, 
PathGraph /@ PropertyValue[{g, t}, "ShortestPaths"]}]
```

Note, if I run similar code on a different graph, it runs fine:

[image]

Comment: Edited now and added the missing function FanOutBlingBsTimes. Refreshed kernel and it runs as expected (with the error I indicated)

Comment: The following code runs fine, so not sure what I can narrow down         BreadthFirstScan[g, s, {"DiscoverVertex" -> discoverFun, 
     "VisitedVertex" -> rediscoverFun, 
     "UnvisitedVertex" -> rediscoverFun}]

Comment: @Kuba not sure where your comments went. In any case, I fixed matters and the error should hopefully be clear now.

Comment: @Szabolcs I posted the new version. Not sure where the error in PropertyValue[{g, t}, "ShortestPaths"] at end of code arises from. BreadthFirstScan just before that line runs fine.

Comment: I tried adding reap and sow commands to discoverFun and rediscoverFun to pin down the problem further, but obtained no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that this doesn't print anything:

```
In[84]:= If[x != 1, Print["a"], Print["b"]]

Out[84]= If[x != 1, Print["a"], Print["b"]]
```

But this **does** print something:

```
In[85]:= If[x =!= 1, Print["a"], Print["b"]]

During evaluation of In[85]:= a
```

This is the source of your problem; using `Unequal` and `Equal` instead of `UnsameQ` and `SameQ`.

Comment: Thanks Jason, could you clarify why my second example graph works and not the first example graph (in relation to the use of UnsameQ and SameQ and Unequal and Equal mixup)?

Comment: All I can say is that your `discoverFun` and `rediscoverFun` aren't actually setting any property values as they are written.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it more closely. But my code appears to run fine now (bar some issues with the highlighting at the end which does not show up). The main problem I am having seems to be fixed indeed. Much appreciated.

Comment: They are not really my discoverFun and rediscoverFun. They were supplied in Mathematica documentation (for a graph on which they ran fine). I have flagged it in a comment to Mathematica feedback as it would make the code more generally applicable.